# Jokes in the sense of Littlewood: examples?

Tags: soft-question, big-list, examples

First, let me make it clear that I do *not* mean jokes of the
"abelian grape" variety. I take my cue from the following 
passage in *A Mathematician's Miscellany* by J.E. Littlewood
(Methuen 1953, p. 79):

> I remembered the Euler formula $\sum n^{-s}=\prod (1-p^{-s})^{-1}$;
>   it was introduced to us at school, as a *joke* (rightly enough, and
>   in excellent taste).

Without trying to define Littlewood's concept of joke, I venture
to guess that another in the same category is the formula

> $1+2+3+4+\cdots=-1/12$,

which Ramanujan sent to Hardy in 1913, admitting "If I tell you this 
you will at once point out to me the lunatic asylum as my goal."

Moving beyond zeta function jokes, I would suggest that the empty
set in ZF set theory is another joke in excellent taste. Not only
does ZF take the empty set seriously, it uses it to build the whole
universe of sets.

Is there an interesting concept lurking here -- a class of
mathematical ideas that look like jokes to the outsider, but which
turn out to be important? If so, let me know which ones appeal to
you.

Comment: Don't think it's exactly the same concept but Scott Aaronson has a post on something similar here: http://scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=392

Comment: In regard to the empty set being a joke, Frank Harary and Ronald Read wrote a 1974 paper entitled "Is the null graph a pointless concept?".

Comment: It's amazing to see how many such jokes involve geometric series.

Comment: I just noticed that there are two puns in "abelian grape variety," as variety can associate with abelian or with grape. Too bad this is the kind of joke you don't mean. 

Comment: The two most recent answers have been more-or-less duplicates of previous answers. Time to close?

Comment: Why is the Euler formula a joke? Is the proof I saw not “correct”?

Answer (score 189):

Let "$\int$" denote $\int_0^x$. We want to find the solution to

$$\int f = f-1.$$

We simply "factor out" $f$, getting $1=\left(1-\int\right)f$. Thus, $f=(1-\int)^{-1}1$.

Using the geometric series,

$$f=\left(1+\int+\iint+\iiint+\cdots\right)1=1+\int_0^x1~dx+\int_0^x\int_0^x1~dx+\cdots$$

Thus,

$$f=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\cdots=e^x,$$

as expected. (This was told to me by Steve Miller)

Comment: I was going to give this example! It is from a classic book by W. W. Sawyer, Prelude to mathematics. What makes this example interesting is that Sawyer described precisely the phenomenon we are discussing here: to a mathematics student, it appears to be a joke, but in fact, this is a standard technique of solving integral equations. Just to appreciate how a good a joke it is, the passage in Sawyer's book I quoted by memory I read over 20 years ago!

Comment: @Victor. I read some of those W.W. Sawyer books too, and they may
have planted the seed of this question in my mind. Alas, it was
50+ years ago, and I no longer remember what I read in them.

Answer (score 150):

The geometric series expansion of projective space:  $\frac{\mathbf{C}^{n+1} - \mathrm{pt}}{\mathbf{C} - \mathrm{pt}} = \mathbf{C}^n + \cdots + \mathbf{C}^1 + \mathrm{pt}$

Comment: This is great!  There's no actual "good" reason for this (e.g. a perspective in which CW complexes correspond to formal polynomials / power series), is there?

Comment: Aaron, I find John Baez's perspective here http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week184.html to be quite interesting.

Comment: @Aaron: This equation holds in the Grothendieck ring of varieties (sometimes called ``ring of motives of varieties'' or similar). Whenever you have a Zariski locally trivial fibration $X \to Y$ with every fiber isomorphic to $F$, then 
$[X] = [F] * [Y]$ in the Grothendieck ring.

Comment: @Arend: I don't know if that counts as a good reason -- the Grothendieck ring is just basically the place where you define this equality to be true! 

Comment: This equation is fantastic!

Comment: @Vivek: that doesn't mean the equation doesn't have content, e.g. it is meaningful to know that in the Grothendieck ring the terms don't all collapse to zero.  (At least, I assume that they don't.)

Comment: @Qiaochu: The terms don't collapse -- one knows from (say) the theory of mixed hodge structures that the virtual Poincare polynomial factors through the Grothendieck ring.  

Answer (score 97):

If $1-ab$ is invertible for $a$, $b$ in a (noncommutative) ring then so is $1-ba$.

Proof:
$$(1-ba)^{-1} = 1+ba +baba+\cdots = 1+b(1+ab+abab+\cdots)a = 1+b(1-ab)^{-1}a,$$
The meaningless infinite series  give the right answer (which is hard to guess).

Comment: There was a "rational" explanation for this sometime ago on MO; maybe someone with better MO-searching fu than I can find it.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31595/how-would-you-solve-this-tantalizing-halmos-problem

Comment: If you think of products of a's and b's as regular expressions, with $(1-x)^{-1}$ playing the role of $x^{\ast}$, the result is fairly obvious. This type of reasoning is, to some extent, captured by [Kleene algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_algebra).

Answer (score 90):

The Cayley-Hamilton Theorem:

If $A$ is a square matrix with characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda) = \det(A-\lambda I)$, then $p(A) = 0$.

Because you know, you "just plug in."

Comment: There are some funny proofs of this, too.  Here's one that works over any field: First notice that the theorem holds for diagonalizable matrices.  Then, adjoin $n^2$ indeterminants to our field and take the algebraic closure.  But the $n \times n$ matrix whose entries are those indeterminants is now diagonalizable!  Thus, we've proved the Cayley-Hamilton theorem as a polynomial identity over our original field.

Comment: That's the first proof of Cayley-Hamilton that I've actually liked....

Comment: This works for selfadjoint operator right? (is it call functional calclus or something?)

Comment: @GeneS.Kopp: doesn't your proof apply verbatim to the polynomial $\Pi(x-\lambda_i)$, where $\lambda_i$ are distinct eigenvalues without multiplicity?

Comment: @Michael: I'm not quite sure what you're getting at.  The $\lambda_i$ live in $\overline{K(x_{11}, x_{12}, \cdots, x_{nn})}$ but not in $K(x_{11}, x_{12}, \cdots, x_{nn})$, so that doesn't tell you anything downstairs.

Comment: @GeneS.Kopp: why is that matrix diagonalizable again?

Comment: @Michael Consider the characteristic polynomial of this matrix. It is enough to show that its discriminant is nonzero (since this implies distinct eigevalues, hence diagonalizable). This discriminant is a polynomial in the indeterminates, and specializing the values will give you discriminants of characteristic polynomials of any matrix. Now it is enough to note that we can always plug in values which result in a matrix with distinct eigenvalues.

Answer (score 83):

In the same vein as the "Freshman's dream"
$$(a + b)^p = a^p + b^p,$$
which is true in characteristic $p$, there is also the "Sophomore's dream", which is the identity
$$\int_{0}^{1}{x^{-x} \: dx} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n^{-n}}.$$
Surprisingly enough, this identity is actually correct.

Comment: Nice! This joke has a long pedigree, going back to a formula of Johann
Bernoulli (1697): $\int^{1}_0 x^x dx=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n n^{-n}$. But it makes a much better joke with the sign change.

Answer (score 72):

The fundamental axioms of mathematics are inconsistent if
and only if we can prove that they are consistent.

(Because, you know, it follows from "logic." See [Second
Incompleteness
theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems))

Comment: As Torkel Franzen pointed out in his wonderful book *Godel's Theorem: An Incomplete Guide to Its Use and Abuse*, if you harbored serious doubts about the consistency of your axioms, why would you be seek a consistency proof in that same setting?

Comment: But would a naive person be upset to find a proof of
consistency in a supposedly rock-solid system? Probably
not---but the joke here is that, nevertheless, they should
be upset, as it reveals inconsistency.

Answer (score 68):

Tim Gowers mentioned infinities that may sound like jokes, especially to outsiders. Here is one specific example: you are standing in a room; at every tick of the clock, someone throws in a pair of numbered ping-pong balls: 1 & 2, then 3 & 4, etc... and you only have enough time to throw out **one** of them before the next tick. If you throw out the one with the **largest** number, then after $\omega$ ticks of the clock, you are in the room with all the odd-numbered balls, whereas if you always threw out the ball with the **smallest** number, you would be rid of them all!

And what if the balls are **not** numbered? A good way to get non-mathematicians thinking about infinity.

Comment: A similar example is _The Gnome and the Pearl of Wisdom: A Fable_ by Richard Willmott (animations at http://www.komal.hu/cikkek/egyeb/torpe/torpe.h.shtml).  This is about a sequence of numbered boxes and numbered marbles.  The boxes start out empty, then in step $ t $, the gnome puts the stone number $ t $ to box $ 0 $, then resolves the conflict of two stones being in the same box by repeatedly moving the stone with the higher number (in the first variation; lower number in the second variation) to the next box.  The question is where are the stones after $\omega$ steps.

Comment: An interesting practical application. Very Clever!

Answer (score 65):

Nobody mentioned the [third isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/third_isomorphism_theorem) yet? If $B$ and $C$ are normal subgroups of $A$ and $C \le B$ then $\frac{A/C}{B/C} \cong \frac{A}{B}$.

Comment: +1 for the user name.

Comment: I don't get this one.  The proof for integers is very close to the proof for groups (if you are thinking about integers as cardinalities of sets)

Answer (score 60):

Another example from intro calculus: I once put a question of the form "$y=f(x)^{g(x)}$, find $y'$" on an exam. One student reasoned, if the exponent were a constant, the answer would be $g(x)f(x)^{g(x)-1}f'(x)$, but that's not right; if the base were a constant, the answer would be $g'(x)f(x)^{g(x)}\log f(x)$, but that's not right either; so I'll put them together to get $$g(x)f(x)^{g(x)-1}f'(x)+g'(x)f(x)^{g(x)}\log f(x)$$This joke was on me, since that turns out to be correct.

Comment: In graduate school I graded one of the questions on a multiple section exam in beginning calculus. The correct answer was 4, and many many students got that, but few by any correct route. My conclusion, as the derivative is a limit process, was that the set consisting of the single number 4 is dense in the real line. 

Comment: Of course, this is just the multivariate chain rule $\frac{d}{dx}f(u(x),v(x)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dx}$. Perhaps your student was motivated by the product rule $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$, which works the same way.

Comment: It has naturaly physical sense: if $x$ arises several times in our expression, we may consider small peturbations (from the definition of derivative) of $x$ being independent and then sum up.

Comment: I noticed this myself a long time ago (for the special case y=x^x), but always thought it was a cute coincidence -- I never realized that it was the multivariate chain rule!

Answer (score 57):

Mazur's proof that knots do not have inverses under addition of knots:
If $A+B=0$, then $$A = A + (B+A)+(B+A)+\cdots=(A+B)+(A+B)+\cdots=0.$$
This is like the traditional joke proof that $1=0$ with $A=1$, $B=-1$; the difference is that the proof with knots is valid because the infinite sums of knots are meaningful: make the knots smaller and smaller.

Comment: That is the Eilenberg swindle (or Eilenberg-Mazur swindle) I briefly mentioned in my answer. A great "Littlewood joke".

Answer (score 55):

The [field with one element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element) seems a good example.

Comment: e.g. $A_n = \mathbb{P}GL_n(\mathbb{F}_1)$

Comment: I've met this one in a presentation where I was told that the Gauss binomial coefficient $ \genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{}{n}{k}_q $ is the number of $ k $ dimensional subspaces in an $ n $ dimensional projective space over the field $ GF_q $.  


Answer (score 54):

The chain rule, in the form $${dy\over dx}={dy\over du}{du\over dx}$$ is a joke - you just cancel the $du$, top and bottom.

Comment: This is not a joke, you CAN cancel those du's, if understood properly. Namely, if we have graph of f(x), and a tangent vector v at point (c, f(c)), then dy = dy(v) = projection of v to y-coordinate, dx = dx(v) = projection of v to x-coordinate. Their quotient dy(v)/dx(v) is equal to f'(c).


Comment: And exactly this isn't the "proper understanding" of the term "du". The conflict here is between a single "du" which is a differential form and cannot be divided (or cancelled out for that matter) and the notational convention to write derivatives as dy/du

Comment: mathreader: indeed you can do that, but it's still a joke in the sense this question asks.  

Comment: Well, if you have two differentials which are dependent in the sense that $dx \wedge dy = 0$ then there is of course some function such that $dy$ = $f dx$.  What could $f$ be called but $dy / dx$?  Since $\mathbb{R}$ is one-dimensional, the chain rule joke always works.

Comment: @mathreader: Be very careful.  What happens if u'(x) = 0?

Comment: In fact, this is the very first thing that came to mind when I read the question.

Comment: @JohannesHahn In nonstandard analysis, it is literally multiplying fractions.

Answer (score 49):

I want to evaluate $f(x+t)$. This is a function of two variables, but let's consider it a function $F(t)$ whose value is a function of $x$, i. e., $F(t)(x) = f(x+t)$. Note that $F(0) = f$, and in general $F$ satisfies the differential equation 
$$F'(t) = D_x(F(t))$$ (both sides being the function $x\mapsto f'(x+t)$). But $D_x$ is just a linear operator, so this is just a homogeneous linear ODE with constant coefficients. The solution is thus $$f(x+t) = F(t)(x) = (e^{tD_x}F(0))(x) = (e^{tD_x}f)(x)
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{((tD_x)^nf)(x)}{n!}
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}.$$ Voilà, Taylor series!

Comment: I love this joke! It appears as Exercise 14.6.3 in Arnol'd's book "Ordinary Differential Equations".

Comment: a trivial remark: this joke is apparently taken seriously by Lie theorists (their exp map)

Answer (score 48):

A typical proof of Kolmogorov's zero-one law has as its punchline 'therefore A is independent of A'.  Perhaps not a joke in the sense of Littlewood, but amusing nonetheless.

Answer (score 42):

A good joke about infinity is the following. A hotel has rooms $1,2,\dots$. Every room is full when a new guest arrives. The clerk moves the occupant of room $n$ to $n+1$ to make room for the new guest in room 1. An hour later another guest arrives and the clerk repeats the 
process. 30 minutes later a third guest arrives and the process is repeated. Then 15 minutes, 7.5 minutes, etc., until two hours after the first new guest infinitely many guests have arrived and been accommodated. The clerk is very pleased with himself for dealing with these infinitely many guests, when he notices to his horror that all the rooms are empty! All the guests have mysteriously disappeared!

Comment: Is this Achilbert and the Tortoise, or what?...

Comment: Right, this is isomorphic to the take about The Gnome and the Pearl of Wisdom which I just mentioned above.


Answer (score 41):

An expansion on Timothy Chow's example of Grandi's series $1 - 1 + 1 - 1 \pm \cdots = \frac{1}{2}$.  It is possible to interpret the left hand side as computing the Euler characteristic of infinite real projective space $\mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$, which is a $K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, 1)$ and therefore rightfully has orbifold Euler characteristic $\frac{1}{2}$!  I think I learned this example from somewhere on Wikipedia.

Comment: I think you learned it from TWF, right?

Answer (score 39):

We owe Paul Dirac two excellent mathematical jokes. I have amended them with a few lesser known variations.

A. *Square root of the Laplacian*: we want $\Delta$ to be $D^2$ for some first order differential operator (for example, because it is easier to solve first order partial differential equations than second order PDEs). Writing it out,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_k^2}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right) = \sum_{i,j}\gamma_i\gamma_j \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i x_j},
$$

and equating the coefficients, we get that this is indeed true if

$$D=\sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\quad\text{and}\quad \gamma_i\gamma_j+\gamma_j\gamma_i=2\delta_{ij}.$$ (With a $2$ on the right hand side.)

It remains to come up with the right $\gamma_i$'s. Dirac realized how to accomplish it with $4\times 4$ matrices when $n=4$; but a neat follow-up joke is to simply define them to be the elements $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n$ of

$$\mathbb{R}\langle\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n\rangle/(\gamma_i\gamma_j+\gamma_j\gamma_i - 2\delta_{ij}).$$

---

Using symmetry considerations, it is easy to conclude that the commutator of the $n$-dimensional Laplace operator $\Delta$ and the multiplication by $r^2=x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2$ is equal to $aE+b$, where
$$E=x_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\cdots+x_n\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}$$ is the Euler vector field. A boring way to confirm this and to determine the coefficients $a$ and $b$ is to expand $[\Delta,r^2]$ and simplify using the commutation relations between $x$'s and $\partial$'s. A more exciting way is to act on $x_1^\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is a formal variable:

$$[\Delta,r^2]x_1^{\lambda}=((\lambda+2)(\lambda+1)+2(n-1)-\lambda(\lambda-1))x_1^{\lambda}=(4\lambda+2n)x_1^{\lambda}.$$

Since $x_1^{\lambda}$ is an eigenvector of the Euler operator $E$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, we conclude that

$$[\Delta,r^2]=4E+2n.$$

---

B. *Dirac delta function*: if we can write

$$g(x)=\int g(y)\delta(x-y)dy$$

then instead of solving an inhomogeneous linear differential equation $Lf=g$ for each $g$, we can solve the equations $Lf=\delta(x-y)$ for each real $y$, where a linear differential operator $L$ acts on the variable $x,$ and combine the answers with different $y$ weighted by $g(y)$. Clearly, there are fewer real numbers than functions, and if $L$ has constant coefficients, using translation invariance the set of right hand sides is further reduced to just one, $\delta(x)$. In this form, the joke goes back to Laplace and Poisson.

---

What happens if instead of the ordinary geometric series we consider a doubly infinite one? Since

$$z(\cdots + z^{-n-1} + z^{-n} + \cdots + 1 + \cdots + z^n + \cdots)= 
\cdots + z^{-n} + z^{-n+1} + \cdots + z + \cdots + z^{n+1} + \cdots,$$

the expression in the parenthesis is annihilated by the multiplication by $z-1$, hence it is equal to $\delta(z-1)$. Homogenizing, we get

$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(\frac{z}{w}\right)^n=\delta(z-w)$$

This identity plays an important role in conformal field theory and the theory of vertex operator algebras.

---

Pushing infinite geometric series in a different direction,

$$\cdots + z^{-n-1} + z^{-n} + \cdots + 1=-\frac{z}{1-z} \quad\text{and}
\quad 1 + z + \cdots + z^n + \cdots = \frac{1}{1-z},$$

which add up to $1$. This time, the sum of doubly infinite geometric series is zero!
Thus the point $0\in\mathbb{Z}$ is the sum of all lattice points on the non-negative half-line and all points on the positive half-line:

$$0=[\ldots,-2,-1,0] + [0,1,2,\ldots] $$

A vast generalization is given by Brion's formula for the generating function for the lattice points in a convex lattice polytope $\Delta\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ with vertices $v\in{\mathbb{Z}}^N$ and closed inner vertex cones $C_v\subset\mathbb{R}^N$:

$$\sum_{P\in \Delta\cap{\mathbb{Z}}^N} z^P = 
\sum_v\left(\sum_{Q\in C_v\cap{\mathbb{Z}}^N} z^Q\right),$$

where the inner sums in the right hand side need to be interpreted as rational functions in $z_1,\ldots,z_N$.

---

Another great joke based on infinite series is the [Eilenberg swindle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg_swindle), but I am too exhausted by fighting the math preview to do it justice.

Comment: In a similar spirit as the first joke: how does one "get" a "root" (=usually a complicated thingie) of a polynomial $f(X)\in A[X]$? Well, consider the element $\overline{X}\in A[X]/(f)$.

Answer (score 38):

Multiplication is repeated addition:
$$
 x^2 = \underbrace{x+\cdots+x}_{x\text{ times}}
$$

Differentiate (remember the chain rule for partial derivatives):

$$\frac{d}{dx} \big(x^2\big)\qquad\qquad$$

$$ \qquad= {\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{x\text{ times}}}$$

$$\qquad{}+ \underbrace{x+\cdots+x}_{1\text{ times}}$$

$$ \qquad= x + x = 2x .$$

Comment: I took the liberty of changing "+x+\cdots+x" to "{}+x+\cdots+x".  That puts a larger amount of space between the first "+" and the "x", thus: $+x+\cdots+x$ versus ${}+x+\cdots+x$.  When you understand why that is just how the software _ought_ to work, then you will understand something about typesetting and about the fact that Donald Knuth (inventor of TeX, among other things) knew what he was doing. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 37):

In characteristic $p$, the so-called *biologists' rule*

$$(a+b)^p = a^p + b^p$$
 (which got its name by mathematics students that worked as teaching assistants for "mathematics for biologists") is correct.

Comment: I've heard this called the "freshman's dream".

Comment: Yes, in fact Thomas Hungerford's book Algebra calls it that way in Exercise 11 in page 121. And according to it, the terminology is due to V.O. McBrien.

Comment: or "freshman's delight"

Comment: In German: Klein Fritzchens binomische Formel.

Comment: Or "Idiot's Binomial Theorem"

Answer (score 36):

In a probability oral exam, a student is asked to compute the probability that a random number 
chosen from the interval $[0,1]$ is larger than $2/3$. The students answers $1/3$. The teacher asks him to explain his argument, and he says: well, there are three possibilities: the number is either less than, or bigger than, or equal to $2/3$, so, the probability is $1/3$!

Answer (score 35):

The classical Stokes formula $\int_{\partial\Omega}\omega=\int_\Omega d\omega$ is certainly a Littlewood type joke. That is especially true if you learn it after you've spent a few months covering vector calculus, learned rotor, divergence, path and surface integrals of 2 kinds, etc., which is the standard route to follow.

Answer (score 34):

There are other divergent series that fit the bill, such as $1-1+1-1+ \cdots = 1/2$.  Here's one from formal language theory: Suppose we define a language $L$ recursively by the rule $L = 1 | aL$, meaning that the empty string $1$ is in $L$, and the letter $a$ followed by any element in $L$ is also in $L$.  Jokingly, we note that $|$ is akin to addition and concatenation is akin to multiplication, so we can solve for $L$: $1 = L - aL  = L (1-a)$, so
$$L = {1\over 1-a} = 1|a|aa|aaa|aaaa \ldots,$$
which is the right answer.

The [umbral calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus) could also be considered an elaborate joke.

Comment: Nice example. I like the fact that the very name "umbral
calculus" admits its shady nature.

Comment: There is a nice piece of algebra with structure types at http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week202.html . Actually, John Baez's TWF is full of "jokes" (as in, concrete mathematics from a ridiculously abstract viewpoint that actually makes hard things trivial).

Comment: @JOhn, is that the actual origin of the use of that word?

Comment: Dear Mariano, I think that "umbral calculus" was coined by Sylvester.
Looking on Mathworld confirms this, but (according to Mathworld) the shadows being alluded to are the combinatorial identities obtained, which "shadow" more obvious polynomial or Taylor series idenities.

Comment: @Mariano: The term "umbra" (shadow) is attributed to Sylvester, and 
its first occurrence seems to be the following, from 1851 (in his 
*Collected Mathematical Papers* vol. 1, p.242):

"Each quantity is now represented by two letters; the letters themselves, 
taken separately, being symbols neither of quantity nor of operation,
but mere umbrae or ideal *elements* of quantitative symbols."

Comment: Dear John, This is more appealing and romantic than the Mathworld explanation, and presumably more accurate, since you are quoting Sylvester directly.  I wonder if the Mathworld explanation is just based on speculation rather than primary sources?

Answer (score 32):

How many finite sets are there?

Well, there is one set of cardinality 0; one set of cardinality one; one set of cardinality 2, but since its automorphism group has order 2, we only count it with multiplicity 1/2; there is one set of cardinality 3, counted with multiplicity 1/3!; ...
So the number of sets is
$$
1 + 1+ 1/2! + 1/3! + \dots = e
$$

Comment: So $e$ is the Euler number of the space, or category, or something, of finite sets.

Comment: It's the Euler number of the _groupoid_ of finite sets.

Answer (score 31):

This is a souped-up version of the freshman's dream: as Jon Borwein pointed out to me: if $a_n=(-1)^n/(2n+1)$, then $$\left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n\right)^2=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n^2$$ as they are both $\pi^2/4$.

Moreover, this can be proved by telescoping sums:
$$
\begin{align}
\left( \sum_{n} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \right)^2 &= \sum_{m,n} \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{(2m+1)(2n+1)} \\
&= \sum_{m,k} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2m+1)(2m+2k+1)} \\
&= \sum_{m} \frac{1}{(2m+1)^2} + \sum_{k \neq 0 } \sum_m \left( \frac{(-1)^k}{2 k (2m+1)} - \frac{(-1)^k}{2 k (2m+2k+1)} \right) \\
&= \sum_{m} \frac{1}{(2m+1)^2}
\end{align}$$
Of course, one needs to justify rearranging the conditionally convergent series, but that spoils the joke.

Answer (score 29):

I know you say "moving beyond zeta function jokes", but I'd say the following two zeta-regularizations deserve to be alongside your Ramanujan example:
$$\infty!= \sqrt{2\pi}\qquad\qquad\mbox{and }\qquad\qquad
\prod_{\mbox{$p$ prime}}p =4\pi^2.$$
One can also entertain beginning calculus students with $\frac{1}{2}!=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}$ as a way of introducing the Gamma function.

Answer (score 23):

Given a function $f$ on the real line, let's compute the function
$\sum f$, taking $n \mapsto f(1) +\cdots + f(n)$. Well, $\sum = 1/\Delta$,
where $\Delta$ is the differencing operator $\text{shift} - 1$. And the shift
operator is the exponential of the differentiation operator (this being,
essentially, Taylor's theorem). Hence
$$ \sum = \frac{1}{e^D - 1} = \frac{1}{D} \frac{D}{e^D-1} $$
Using L'Hopital's rule on the latter as $D\to 0$, 
whatever THAT means, we see the limit is $1$. So expand in a power series:
$$ \frac{1}{D} \frac{D}{e^D-1} = \frac{1}{D} (1 + \text{power series in $D$}) $$
The first term is $1/D$, which is of course $\int$.

No surprise:
$\sum = \int + $ correction terms. What the above suggests is that those 
correction terms come from the Taylor expansion of $\frac{D}{e^D - 1}$.
This leads to the Euler summation formula (and eventually, to
Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch).

I learned this from "Concrete Mathematics", where I recall this joke
being attributed to Laguerre. Part of why it is a joke is that the Euler
summation formula has an *error term*, that can't be neglected for most
functions, e.g. $\ln(x)$ which one wants to sum up to compute $\ln(n!)$. 
It can be neglected for polynomials times exponentials.

Comment: Victor Protsak hinted at this joke in his comment of 17 September on Per Vognsen's contribution. 

Comment: @‍PerVognsen's [contribution](https://mathoverflow.net/a/39049) and @‍VictorProtsak's [hint](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38856/jokes-in-the-sense-of-littlewood-examples?page=2#comment91504_39049) [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38856/jokes-in-the-sense-of-littlewood-examples#comment115635_47757) by @GerryMyerson.

Answer (score 22):

Let $C(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{n+1} {2n \choose n} x^n$ be the generating function for the Catalan numbers.  Then $C(x) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - 4x}}{2}$.  In particular, $C(1) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{-3}}{2}$ is a sixth root of unity - except of course that $C(1)$ does not converge.

Nevertheless, there is a remarkable sense in which $C^7 = C$; see Blass' *[Seven Trees in One](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9405205)* and the generalization in Fiore and Leinster's *[Objects of Categories as Complex Numbers](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212377v1)*.  As with many results of this type, I learned about this from [John Baez's TWF 202](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week202.html).

Comment: I think the second author ought to be "Leinster," though I would love to take credit since I like that paper very much. :)

Comment: That Fiore-Leinster paper is hilarious! I must read it someday, when I find the time.

Answer (score 22):

I do a double take every couple of months when I remember that

$(1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n)^2 = 1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + \ldots + n^3$

It just seems plain weird.

Comment: http://users.tru.eastlink.ca/~brsears/math/oldprob.htm#s32

Answer (score 21):

Lagrange's equation:

$$\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}} \mathcal{L} \right) =\frac{\partial}{\partial q} \mathcal{L},$$

as $\dot{q}=\frac{dq}{dt}$, you can simplify "$dt$".

Answer (score 19):

Here's one of my own.  Maybe I should publish it?  A confused calculus student attempted to evaluate
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( 1^n + 2^n + 3^n +  \cdots + (x-1)^n \right)
$$
and got
$$
n1^{n-1} + n2^{n-1} + n3^{n-1} + \cdots + n(x-1)^{n-1} + \text{constant}.
$$
That is in fact correct.  The "constant" is a Bernoulli number.

Comment: PS: Not a true story.  The "confused student" is fictitious.

Answer (score 17):

This was once presented to me as a kind of proof, though I think it works better as a kind of joke:

To compute ${\partial^n\over\partial x^n}(fg)$, split ${\partial\over\partial x}$ into the sum of a piece $D$ that just acts on $f$ (acting as the identitiy on $g$) and a piece $E$ that just acts on $g$ (acting as the identity on $f$) and write
${\partial^n\over\partial x^n}(fg) = (D+E)^n(fg) = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} D^i E^{n-i}(fg) = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} {\partial^i f\over\partial x^i}{\partial^{n-i} g\over\partial x^{n-i}}$.

Comment: Some things about this kind of derivative are clearer if you first think of it as $\displaystyle\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x_1\,\cdots\,\partial x_n}(fg)$ and then _after_ finding the derivative let the $n$ variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ coalesce into indistinguishability. What happens is that before they coalesce, every coefficient in the expansion is $1$, but after they coalesce the coefficients simply count the number of terms in a class of terms that become indistinguishable from each other. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 16):

This isn't a particularly interesting example, but the existence of different sizes of infinity fits your criterion of being something that makes outsiders laugh (as I know from experience) and that is also very important to mathematicians.

The familiar argument that says that if you want an explicit example of $a^b=c$ with a and b irrational and c rational, then one of $a=b=\sqrt{2}$ or $a=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ and $b=\sqrt{2}$ will work is certainly an argument that makes people laugh. Though the result itself is not very important, the phenomenon it illustrates is quite important.

Added two minutes later: I've just had a look at Scott Aaronson's post and seen that Erik, one of the earlier commenters, chose precisely the same two examples. It was a coincidence -- honest.

Answer (score 12):

Another geometric series joke:

Let $S_\epsilon$ be the $\epsilon$-shift operator and let $D = (1 - S_\epsilon)/\epsilon$ be the formal derivative operator. Then $D^{-1} = \epsilon \sum_{n=0}^\infty {S_\epsilon}^n$, so $(D^{-1}f)(x) = \epsilon(f(x) + f(x-\epsilon) + f(x-2\epsilon) + \cdots)$, the integral of $f$ from $-\infty$ to $x$. Thus differentiation and integration are inverses.

Playing a prank with the binomial formula on $D$ yields fractional derivatives, another famous joke.

John kicked off the thread with zeta functions; my favorite zeta function joke has to be Euler's solution to the Basel problem where he factored $sin(x)$ as a power series according to its roots $\pm n\pi$.

Comment: An even more impressive version of the shift operator-derivative "geometric series joke" is the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula.

Answer (score 11):

The number of finite sets is $e$.

(Since of course we should count in the stack sense: up to isomorphism, dividing by the number of automorphisms).

Comment: This is the same as the answer of AByer on 17 September, no?

Comment: Oops! I missed his answer when I read through them the first time. I think he actually heard this joke from me in last summer though.  :-).

Comment: @‍ArendBayer's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/39046) [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38856/jokes-in-the-sense-of-littlewood-examples#comment96343_40912) by @GerryMyerson.

Answer (score 9):

$$\dfrac{16}{64} = \dfrac{1\not{6} }{\not{6} 4} = \dfrac{1}{4}$$

$$25^{1/2} = \not25^{1/\not2} = 5^1 = 5$$

$$\sqrt[6]{64} = \sqrt[\not 6]{\not 64} = \sqrt{4}$$

Comment:   For related developments in this important area, see B. Ruekberg, "Simplified Mathematics,". J. Irreproducible Results 35 (1), 1990.

Comment: Don't forget that by crossing off the $9$'s we get $\frac {95}{19}=5$.

Comment: $\frac{sin x}{n} = 6$, just cancel n's, you get "six"

Comment: For reference, a copy of B. Ruekberg can be found here: https://archives.scovetta.com/pub/textfiles/humor/computer/maths.txt
And the case of fractions is elaborated further on Math Stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49657

Answer (score 9):

The chain rule "joke" reminded me of a similar notation joke: Radon-Nikodym derivatives.

If $\mu$, $\nu$, $\lambda$ are $\sigma$-finite measures with $\nu \ll \mu \ll \lambda$, and $f \geq 0$ is measurable, then:

$$\int f\ d\nu = \int f \left[\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right]\ d\mu$$

and

$$\left[\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}\right] = \left[\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right]\left[\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}\right]$$

Comment: When taken seriously, this joke could lead one to discover Yamagami's modular algebra and Tomita-Takesaki theory.

Answer (score 8):

Hausdorff dimension.  Try showing a Sierpinski triangle to a non-mathematician and explaining that it is a 1.585-dimensional object.

Comment: And then try the same thing with the sierpinksi tetraeder (dimension = 2)

Comment: I just did this to an 11-year-old

Comment: @JohannesHahn I think this makes sense. Imagine your tetrahedron sitting on the table. Pick up the top one of the four mini-tetrahedra and put it onto the table so that its base fits into the triangular hole between the other three. Repeat this process recursively and your Sierpinski tetrahedron will be reduced to a triangle.

Answer (score 8):

In german elementary schools you learn "In Summen kürzen nur die Dummen.", i.e. it is dumb to cancel sums in quotients. But later in algebra or category theory you may learn

$\sum_{i \in I} A_i / \sum_ {i \in I} B_i = \sum_{i \in I} A_i / B_i$,

which is correct.

Comment: You also frequently divide by zero when dealing with abelian groups ;-)

Comment: And does it work? I don't mean the identity; do students remember not to cancel in quotients? If yes, I might start using it...

Comment: Martin, thanks for the great slogan, which I'd like to translate as "Only the
dumb cancel in sums." Probably couldn't use it in the US, alas, it might
hurt the students' self-esteem ...

Comment: The whole thing is because sums in abelian categories are more or less the same as products. If such a rule would hold for tensor division (whatever this could mean), that would be interesting...

Comment: It is a general fact that coproducts commute with cokernels, this holds in every Ab-category. More generally, colimits commute with colimits. Thus it has nothing to do with abelian categories, where also only finite sums are finite products. 

Answer (score 8):

In Cardano's formula for the roots of the cubic there are negative numbers under the square roots if and only if all roots of the polynomial are real.  That, and the fact that Cardano and his contemporaries didn't even believe in negative numbers.

Answer (score 6):

The yoga of motives, in the parts which are conjectural but inspire the right guesses, is a huge joke!

Answer (score 6):

Gerry's answer reminded me of the "Lucky Larry" series, which is a regular column in *The AMATYC Review*.

One particularly nice one is

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln\ln x}{\ln x}$$

where you can cancel the $\ln x$ and wind up with $\ln 1=0$, which turns out correct.

Answer (score 6):

Many infinite, periodic expression involving numbers is a joke, according to non-mathematicians. Three examples:
$$0,999999999\cdots=1,$$
$$1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\cdots}}}=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2},$$
$$\sqrt{-a^2+\sqrt{-a^2+\sqrt{-a^2+\cdots}}}=\frac12(1+\sqrt{1-4a^2}).$$

Answer (score 6):

Two ways to calculate $1+2+3+\dots$

1st way. Let $$1-1+1-1+\dots=a.$$ Then also $$0+1-1+1-1+\dots=a.$$ Sum up (summing respective terms), get $$2a=1+0+0+\dots=1,$$ $a=1/2$.

Let now $$1-2+3-4+\dots=b.$$ Again, write down $$0+1-2+3-\dots=b.$$ Sum up and get  $$2b=1-1+1-1+\dots=1/2,$$ 
$b=1/4$. Now let 
$$
1+ 2+3+ 4+5+\dots=с.
$$
Then 
$$
0+4\cdot 1+0+4\cdot 2+0+4\cdot 3+0+\dots=4с.
$$
Substract and get $$-3с=1-2+3-4+5+\dots=1/4,$$ hence

$$1+2+3+\dots=-1/12.$$

2nd way. Let  $$1+2+3+\dots=S.$$ Then 
$$
2+4+6+\dots=2\cdot(1+2+3+\dots)=2S.
$$ Hence
$$
1+3+5+\dots=(1+2+3+4+5+\dots)-
(0+2+0+4+0+\dots)=-S.
$$

Now sum up $$1+2+3+4+\dots=S$$ and $$0+1+3+5+\dots=-S.$$ We get 
$$
0=1+3+6+9+\dots=1+3\cdot(1+2+3+\dots)=1+3S,
$$

$S=-1/3$. So

$$
1+2+3+\dots=-1/3.
$$

The question is: why the first way gives correct answer $\zeta(-1)=-1/12$, while the second leads to incorrect answer?

Comment: Terence Tao discusses such issues here: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/

Answer (score 5):

I've always thought of compactness arguments for passing from a finite result to an infinite one as sorts of jokes. The general idea, after all, is that to get the infinite analogue of the finite result, you just "make it bigger and bigger!" (Of course it doesn't work in all situations, but when it does it's often forehead-slappingly simple.)

Comment: Nonstandard analysis is one of these jokes.

Answer (score 3):

The Eilenberg swindle was briefly mentioned [by Victor Protsak](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38856/jokes-in-the-sense-of-littlewood-examples/38930#38930), and something which always struck me as similar (and seemed like black magic to me when I first saw it) is the Pelczynski decomposition method for proving that complemented subspaces of $\ell^p$ are isomorphic to $\ell^p$. I don't have a link to hand but might try to write something out later (or someone else is welcome to edit this).

Answer (score 3):

When solving the linear recursive equation
$a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + 2 a_n$, you solve the quadratic equation 
$x^2 = x + 2$, which has the solutions $x= 2$ and $x = -1$, and then you get a basis of solutions $2^n$ and $(-1)^n$.

What if you start with $a_{n+2} = 4a_{n+1} - 4a_n$, so that the quadratic equation
$x^2 = 4x - 4$ has only one solution $x = 2$? Easy, you take the solution $2^n$, and its derivative with respect to 2, i.e. $n \cdot 2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

You can't prove something exists just by computing the probability of its existence - right? The first application of the  ["probabilistic arguments"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method) in Combinatorics I have encountered was  [this;](http://books.google.com/books?id=KvQr9l0wgf8C&lpg=PP1&dq=proofs%20from%20the%20book&pg=PA82#v=onepage&q&f=false) took me a long time to get it.

Comment: "This" is "**Theorem 2**:  For every $d \ge 2$, there is a set $S \subseteq \{0, 1\}^d$ of $2\lfloor(\sqrt6/9)(2/\sqrt3)^d\rfloor$ points in $\mathbb R^d$ that determine only acute angles" (probably).

Answer (score 3):

(An example from set theory, more specifically: forcing):

The backslash $\backslash$ is used for set difference, the forward slash $/$ is often used for taking a quotient.   In my experience, students often have a hard time distinguishing between the two.  (Between the two symbols, not the two concepts.)

But there is one case where the difference does not matter:  if $B$ is a Boolean algebra, and $I$ an ideal, then the sets $B\setminus I$ (= $I$-positive elements)  and $B/I$ (quotient Boolean algebra) are equivalent as forcing notions:  $B\setminus I  = B/I $.

For example, random forcing can be seen as "Borel sets modulo measure zero sets", or equivalently as "Lebesgue-positive Borel sets (without any identification)".

Answer (score 2):

I can't say I share Littlewood's sense of humor, but here is a formula that made me grin the first time I saw it ($A$ and $B$ are non-commuting square matrices):

\begin{equation}\frac{d}{dt}e^{A+B t}=\int_0^1 e^{s(A+B t)}\ B\ e^{(1-s)(A+B t)} \ ds.
\end{equation}

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: Well, it's true -- do you need a proof?

I thought it was funny because integrals are in a sense the opposite of derivatives and yet here the result of a derivative is an integral.

Comment: The Cauchy integral formula would be even funnier then.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I know one proof and one "proof" of this identity, and they're both pretty amusing. The proof (from "Exponential Operators and Parameter Differentiation in Quantum Physics," by R.M. Wilcox) is done by showing that both sides of the identity satisfy the same first-order linear differential equation, with the same initial condition. The "proof," which I've always associated with Richard Feynman, is done by writing exp(A + Bt) as (1 + (A + Bt)/N)^N, for N extremely large, and applying the product rule.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this counts, but here's one of my own devising:

How do we find second derivatives of inverse functions?

Well, the second derivative of $y = f(x)$ is defined as $(f')' = \frac{d\frac{dy}{dx}}{dx}$, and by the quotient rule we can write this as $\frac{dxd^2y-dyd^2x}{dx^3} = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\frac{dyd^2x}{dx^3}.$ (Since $x$ usually varies linearly, we normally substitute $d^2x = 0$.)

So by symmetry, the second derivative of the inverse function is $(f^{-1})'' = \frac{d^2x}{dy^2}-\frac{dxd^2y}{dy^3} = -\frac{dx^3}{dy^3}(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\frac{dyd^2x}{dx^3}) = -f''/(f')^3.$

We can also directly derive the chain rule for second derivatives: Let $x = f(v)$, $v = g(u)$, and we get
$(f\circ g)'' = \frac{d^2x}{du^2} - \frac{dxd^2u}{du^3} = (\frac{d^2x}{dv^2}-\frac{dxd^2v}{dv^3})\frac{dv^2}{du^2}+\frac{dx}{dv}(\frac{d^2v}{du^2}-\frac{dvd^2u}{du^3}) = (f''\circ g)(g')^2 + (f'\circ g)g''.$

---

Here's another one:

A friend of mine (Sam Elder) was trying to calculate the number of combinations on a simplex lock with $n$ buttons. After some work he had gotten a recurrence which I'm going to write as $2A_m = 1+\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k}A_{k}$, which he showed to me. My thought process went like this:

Hmm, this looks like the recurrence for the Bernoulli numbers. How did we prove the recurrence for the Bernoulli numbers again? One way is to use the well-known fact that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^m = -\frac{B_{m+1}}{m+1}$, so
$-\frac{B_{m+1}}{m+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^m = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)^m = -\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\frac{B_{k+1}}{k+1}$.

Working backwards, what I need to do is find a sequence of functions $f_m(n)$ satisfying $2f_m(n+1) = \sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}f_{k}(n)$. This leads naturally to the choice $f_m(n) = \frac{n^m}{2^n}$. So the number of simplex combinations on m buttons is

$A_m = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^m}{2^n}.$

Sam did not find this formula incredibly helpful.

(Continuing the analogy with the Bernoulli numbers, we can also derive the formula
$\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{n^m}{2^n} = A^m-\frac{(x+A)^m}{2^x},$
where we interpret $A^m$ as $A_m$.)

Comment: zeb, I think the formula you've given for A_m is very interesting.  It says that A_m is the mth moment of a geometric distribution and I would love if anyone could give a conceptual explanation why this is the same thing as what it actually counts (which I can't quite recall at the moment).

Comment: The sequence $A_m$ is on the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences as A000629. Apparently I'm not the first one to come up with that formula; maybe the references on OEIS have a more conceptual proof.

Answer (score 2):

For consecutive Farey fractions $\frac{a}{b}, \frac{c}{d}$ the mediant is obtained via a "simple's man addition":
$$ \frac{p}{q} = \frac{a+c}{b+d} $$
which since $\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}$ are consecutive if and only if $det\begin{pmatrix}a & c\\\\ b & d\end{pmatrix} = 1$ also turns out to be the rule of invariance of the determinant when you add a column to another column.

Comment: For consecutive fractions in a Farey sequence $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ is not the sum of $\frac ab$ and $\frac cd$ but rather the next Farey fraction to appear between these two.

Comment: Of course... for some reason i've been thinking that the mediant also had to be equal to the sum. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

I've always seen the following identity for the determinant of block matrices as a 'joke'

$\det\left( \begin{array}{cc} A & B \newline C & D \end{array} \right) = \det(AD-BC)$

Comment: It isn't true for arbitrary square blocks of equal size, but if for example the four matrices commute, then the identity holds. 

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is a silly example, but as far back as grade school I found it amusing (and maybe a little profound) that to invert a fraction $\frac{a}{b}$, you literally invert it! As I learned about more and more mathematical objects through the years, I kept waiting for this kind of thing to happen again, but it never really did.

Comment: I had a 6th grade teacher who demonstrated inversion by calling a 
small kid out of the front row and literally *turning him upside-down*.
With the possible exception of some John Conway's performances, it's 
the most dramatic event I've seen in a mathematics classroom.

Comment: If $y=f(x)$, and you invert the function to get $x=f^{-1}(y)$, then you get the derivative of the inverse function by inverting the derivative of the original function: $dx/dy=1/(dy/dx)$. 

Answer (score 1):

I recall that the following simple "proof" of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ is attributed to Euler:

Begin with the fact that for a polynomial $a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_N x^N$ the sum of the inverses of the roots is given by $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{x_n} = -\frac{a_1}{a_0}$. (If you only remember the formula for the sum of the roots just make a change of variable $y=1/x$). Now consider the "polynomial" $$\frac{\sin\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}} = 1 - \frac{x}{3!} + \cdots$$ whose roots are $x_n = (n\pi)^2$ for $n\in N$. By applying the aforementioned fact the desired result is immediate.

Comment: This was already mentioned by Per Vognsen in his answer of 19 September, no?

Comment: Oh yes; you're right. I did skim through all responses before submitting mine but somehow it didn't capture my attention since it didn't have a big $\pi^2/6$ right at the center! Thanks for the comment and sorry for duplicate answer.

Comment: @‍PerVognsen's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/39049) [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38856/jokes-in-the-sense-of-littlewood-examples#comment96342_40914) by @GerryMyerson.

Answer (score 0):

Another joke in the spirit of the chain rule;  you solve separable differential equations by "multiplying by g(y)dx"
$$g(y) dx \left(\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{f(x)}{g(y)}\right) \Rightarrow g(y)dy = f(x) dx$$

Then, there's nothing to be done but integrating to get rid of the dx and dy.

I also like to point out to students who ask about cancellation in the chain rule that you can cancel there just like you can cancel the sixes and nines respectively in

$$\frac {16}{64} = \frac 1 4 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{19}{95}=\frac 1 5;$$
that is, carefully, and when it makes sense to do so.

Comment: Canceling these digits is a mistake that coincidentally yields the right answer, but multiplying by $g(y)\,dx$ is a "joke" only because the rules haven't been properly codified---like the way Dirac's delta function and its derivatives were a "joke".

Answer (score 0):

Yet another divergence joke:

$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j j!=e E_1(1)\approx 0.596347362\dots$$

where $E_n(z)$ is an [exponential integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2).

This is intimately related to the formal hypergeometric series ${}_2 F_0$ being the asymptotic expansion of a certain convergent improper integral.

This also serves as a warning of sorts to users of convergence acceleration methods like Wynn ε or Levin *t* ; attempts to sum a divergent series might give "correct" yet still unexpected answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's more divergence craziness:

$$\int_0^\infty \sin\;u\mathrm{d}u=1$$

and

$$\int_0^\infty \ln\;u\;\sin\;u\mathrm{d}u=-\gamma$$

($\gamma$ is of course the Euler-Mascheroni constant)

which only makes sense when interpreted as

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \int_0^\infty \exp(-\varepsilon u)\ln\;u\;\sin\;u\mathrm{d}u$$

and similarly for the first one.

Results obtained from numerical quadrature methods specially designed for infinite oscillatory integrals (e.g. the Ooura-Mori double exponential quadrature and the Longman scheme) agree with these closed forms.

Answer (score -3):

The [journal of unpublishable mathematics](http://www.mathematicians.org.uk/jum/), which seems to be down at the moment is one of my favourites

Comment: The journal is a "joke in the sense of Littlewood"?

Comment: I do not know, I never had the chance to meet him to ask ;)

Comment: Right now their is nothing in the journal. I guess unpublishable mathematics does not get published.

Comment: That is the joke

Answer (score -5):

If $\frac{8}{0}= \infty$, then $\frac{n}{0}= n^{'}$, where $n^{'}$ is $n$ rotated by 90 degrees on the right.

Comment: I think a better version of this is $\lim_{\omega\to\infty}3=8$, but I'm not sure this a "joke in the sense of Littlewood." 